# Clone multiple SVN projects with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a large Java app that is split up into multiple projects.  Each project has its own folder in a Subversion repository like so:

AccountingCore

- trunk
- branches
- tags

Common

- trunk
- branches
- tags

WebCommon

- trunk
- branches
- tags

etc...

I want to start using **git-svn** locally instead of subversion.

This may be a stupid question, but is there a way to checkout *all the projects* in the repository at once (including branches and all) instead checking out each project individually?

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a shell, you could enter

`for DIR in AccountingCore Common WebCommon; do mkdir $DIR; cd $DIR; git init; git svn init -s svn://host/path/$DIR; git svn fetch; cd ..; done`

That is, if I made no mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Just to improve on earlier answer, instead of

```
for DIR in AccountingCore Common WebCommon; do ...
```

do

```
DIRS=`svn ls svn://host/path`; for DIR in $DIRS; do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  just checkout at the root path.  If your repo is hosted here:

svn://host/path/AccountingCore
svn://host/path/Common
svn://host/path/WebCommon

Then do your `git svn` command on `svn://host/path`.