# Can git svn init handle sibling directories of trunk/branches/tags that should be part of base checkout

Tags: git, import, git-svn, svn-trunk

The macports svn repository looks like this:

```
  branches/
  contrib/
  distfiles/
  downloads/
  tags/
  trunk/
  users/
```

I want to import this using git svn and use the standard features to correctly interpret the branches and tags.

What I would like to see is a single git repo that has directories

```
  trunk/ 
  contrib/
  distfiles/
  downloads/
  users/
```

In other words I want to retain the branches in the branches directory as branches (for trunk I presume) and the tags as git tags.  However, I want to be able to see both the contents of trunk, contrib, distfiles, downloads and users without switching branches.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898568/multiple-svn-projects-into-one-git-repository?lq=1) however it differs in that these extra directories (contrib, distfiles, downloads, users) don't have their own tags or branches.  Seems to me they should be subdirectories of trunk so an alternative solution would be to somehow check out trunk with these extra subdirectories appearing under trunk.  However, it may be impossible for the reason.

If not any suggestion how to easily deal with this so I can easily browse contrib and trunk at the same time without doing anything really difficult?  I could jury rig it with submodules but that seems to be asking for trouble.

Comment: Looking back I realize this post can easily be interpreted incorrectly.

I **don't** need or want to somehow browse the branches or the tags in the same checkout as the rest of the code.  That's would just be confusing and break the standard git interface.

I *want to make a git repo as if it had always been a git repo*.  That means tags and branches get put in tags and branches but just because  of where they are in the dir tree svn import won't both important them into the same branch as trunk while still grabbing tags and branches.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
git svn clone http://repo_hostname/top_level_dir_above_those
```

Without any options, git svn won't look for branches, and just check the whole thing out like you want.

**UPDATE:**

Following further clarification, there isn't a way for some parts of a git repository to be viewable across all branches at the same revision... git versions the entire directory tree structure.

You can use the above command, however, to checkout each of those top level directories into its own repository, and then use a standard-layout git svn repo for your branches, tags, and trunk.  Keeping them up to date will be a pain, but a shell script can execute a fetch for each repo as a convenience.

Comment: But there *ARE* branches.

I want the branches and tags directories to be converted in some useful fashion to branches/tags while still having access to their sibling directories!

Comment: See edits I made above.  Point is I want a single checkout to let me browse all the non-special directories (not tags/branches) but still import the tags and branches so I can make use of them.

Thus somehow git would seem to need to create branches/tags that apply to only part of repo making me pessimistic.