# How can I make git-svn repos for a large number of projects in the same SVN repository?

Tags: git, svn

I've got a SVN repository that looks something like:

```
\project1
 - branches
 - tags
 - trunk
\project2
 - branches
 - tags
 - trunk
\subfolder
  \project3
    - branches
    - tags
    - trunk
   \another-subfolder
     \project4
       - branches
       - tags
       - trunk
etc
```

There's probably 100 projects or so in here. I'd like to create git-svn repos for each of these, preferably one that mirrors the structure of SVN.

My initial thought was to write a script that walk the SVN tree and do a `git svn -d clone` for each project, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this (or if someone's built a tool so I don't have to do it myself). Is this reasonable, or are there better ways to perform this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split large Git repository into many smaller ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910412/split-large-git-repository-into-many-smaller-ones)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider [Split large Git repository into many smaller ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910412/split-large-git-repository-into-many-smaller-ones) as a duplicate of this question, especially if you want to maintain the link between svn and your git repos, and be able to '`git svn dcommit`' back to the SVN repo.

You can use some tools like svn2git or [svneverever](http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763), a Python tool which will help you detect all the right project directories in order to write a svn2git rules file for those.

The other approach is illustrated by [this article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/02/03/branch-per-feature-how-i-manage-subversion-with-git-branches/) (for multiple branches, but can be applied to multiple projects as well): "Git-SVN? No, Git+SVN".
Ie checkout the right part of your svn repo and initialize a git repo in it.
See also "[Clone multiple SVN projects with git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279144/clone-multiple-svn-projects-with-git-svn)" for an example of this approach .